# difference between utf-8-emacs and utf-8 on Emacs

Tags: emacs, unicode

Or which one should I use for which purposes? Am I right in assuming that the `utf-8-emacs` coding system is for emacs lisp files and the `utf-8` is for text files?

`M-x describe-coding-system` on the two return:

```
U -- utf-8-emacs

Support for all Emacs characters (including non-Unicode characters).
Type: utf-8 (UTF-8: Emacs internal multibyte form)
EOL type: Automatic selection from:
        [utf-8-emacs-unix utf-8-emacs-dos utf-8-emacs-mac]
This coding system encodes the following charsets:
  emacs


U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8)

UTF-8 (no signature (BOM))
Type: utf-8 (UTF-8: Emacs internal multibyte form)
EOL type: Automatic selection from:
        [utf-8-unix utf-8-dos utf-8-mac]
This coding system encodes the following charsets:
  unicode
```

Not sure what is meant by

```
Support for all Emacs characters (including non-Unicode characters).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`utf-8-emacs` supports additional characters such as the internal representation of binary data. As this is a non-standard extension of Unicode, a separate encoding was defined for it so if you use `utf-8` you will not accidentally include these non-standard extensions which could confuse other software.

You can use either encoding for elisp, unless you need to include binary data or obscure characters that are not part of Unicode it won't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`utf-8-emacs` is the encoding used internally by Emacs.  It's visible in a few places (e.g. auto-save files), but as a general rule you should never use it unless you know what you're doing.